# Is it possible to use dask dataframe with teradata python module?

Tags: python, teradata, dask

I have this code:

```
import teradata
import dask.dataframe as dd

login = login
pwd = password

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="CAF", version="1.0",
                                    logConsole=False)

session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", DSN="Teradata",
                                  USEREGIONALSETTINGS='N', username=login,
                                  password=pwd, authentication="LDAP");
```

And the connection is working.

I want to get a dask dataframe. I have tried this:

```
sqlStmt = "SOME SQL STATEMENT"

df = dd.read_sql_table(sqlStmt, session, index_col='id')
```

And I'm getting this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'UdaExecConnection' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to get it working ?

Answer (score 2):

`read_sql_table` expects a SQLalchemy connection string, not a "session" as you are passing. I have not heard of teradata being used via sqlalchemy, but apparently there is at least [one connector](https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata) you could install, and possibly other solutions using the generic ODBC driver.

However, you may wish to use a more direct approach using `delayed`, something like

```
from dask import delayed

# make a set of statements for each partition
statements = [sqlStmt + " where id > {} and id <= {}".format(bounds)
              for bounds in boundslist]  # I don't know syntax for tera

def get_part(statement):
    # however you make a concrete dataframe from a SQL statement
    udaExec = ..
    session = ..
    df = ..
    return dataframe

# ideally you should provide the meta and divisions info here
df = dd.from_delayed([delayed(get_part)(stm) for stm in statements],
                     meta= , divisions=)
```

We will be interested to hear of your success.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have been facing several issues with my code and I was not able to test your suggestion yet. As soon as I test, I'll share the results.